# Cross-region movement - Transferring Big Query and GCS data from US to EU locations

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

For compliance requirements, we would like to move all our Bigquery data and GCS data from US region to EU region.
From my understanding, multi-region is either within US or within EU. There is no cross-region option as such.

Question 1: In order to move the data from US to EU or vice versa, our understanding is that we need explicitly move the data using a storage transfer service. And assuming a cost associated with this movement even though it is within Google cloud?

Question 2: We also think if we can maintain copies at both locations. In this case, Is there a provision for cross-region replication? If so, what would be the associated cost for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question1:

You are moving data from one part of the world to another one. So, yes you will pay the egress cost of the source location.

Sadly, today (November 28th 2023), I can't 100% commit on that cost. Indeed, I reached Google Cloud about a very similar question and my Google Cloud contact told me that the cost page was out of date. The Cloud Storage egress cost should apply (instead of the Compute Engine Networking egress cost as today in the documentation).

---

Question2:

You copy the data, so, you have, at the end, the volume of data duplicated in 2 dataset and you have your storage cost duplicated.

Every time that you want to sync the data, you perform a copy. It's only a copy, and not a smart delta update. So, be careful if you update directly the data in the target dataset: a new copy will override the data!

Instead, use the target dataset as a base to query, and duplicate (again) the data in an independent dataset, where you can add your region specific data

Comment: Is there any restriction in copying the dataset/table name across cross-region. For example: DATASET1 and Customer table. Can I have the same dataset name and table name replicated in a different region? Idea is to use the same code to run query except for the region change?

Comment: The dataset name must be unique per project. My solution is to suffix/prefix the dataset per the region

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, once the dataset is created, the location cannot be changed, but you can copy the dataset to a different location, or manually move (recreate) the dataset in a different location.

The easier approach is copy, you can learn more about the requirements, quotas and limitations here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets

So:

1. There is no need for the transfer service, you can copy datasets to a different location.
2. There is no mechanism for automatic replication across regions. Even a disaster recovery policy will require cross-region datasets copies.

*BigQuery does not automatically provide a backup or replica of your data in another geographic region. You can create cross-region dataset copies to enhance your disaster recovery strategy.*

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/availability#:%7E:text=cross%2Dregion%20dataset%20copies

So in both cases you need to work with dataset copies and deal with data freshness in the second scenario.